# Local users on server are not visible

Tags: windows-server-2008

I have a strange issue on one of the memberservers of our customers.

If I open Computer Management>Local Users and Groups>Users it seems to be empty. Also If I check this in control panel the same thing.

With the net localgroup "Administrators" "NT Authority\Network Service" /add or net localgroup "Administrators" "NT Authority\Local Service" /add command I get the message back that this account already exists.

Running SFC \scannow does not report any issues on the Server.

I am not able to restore a system state on the server due to the fact that the customer suspects this issue occured at least 12 months ago.

Does anyone had the same issue and is there a fix?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 0):

```
It is good security practice to keep local account names hidden to all but 
those with superuser permissions.

In the Control Panel and in
Computer Management > Local Users and Groups > Users 
the account would not appear to local users.
```

Thus, restoring the system data would not make the user appear.